# Critical points up to smooth homotopy

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ and $N $ be closed connected smooth manifolds of dimension $n$.
Let $f: M\rightarrow N$ be a smooth function and not null-homotopic. Is there a smooth homotopy $H: [0,1]\times M\rightarrow N$ such that $ H(0,-) =f$
and $H(1,-)=g$ where $g$ has a finite number of critical points ?
Let assume that $n<4$.
If the answer is negative in general,  can we still say something interesting in the case when $M$ is a the sphere of dimension $n$ ?

Edit: after a remark in the comments, we add the hypothesis that $f$ is not null-homotopic.

Comment: I think that arises in Cerf theory, but I don't know.

Comment: For "critical point" are you talking about the derivative at a point not having full rank? Because if that's your definition then for $n \geq 2$ there are maps such that every map in the homotopy-class has infinitely-many critical points.  It's the fold singularities you can't remove.

Comment: @RyanBudney yes, by critical point I do mean a point where the derivative does not have full rank.

Comment: So I think a counter-example to your hope first arise with null-homotopic maps $S^2 \to S^2$.  Whitney's theory tells you generic maps have folds and cusps, but since the map is degree 0 you know there has to be folds -- if the map didn't have folds it would be a covering map, and not null-homotopic.  I think you could likely make this argument work for null-homotopic maps $S^n \to S^n$, for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: @RyanBudney excellent! I'm wondering what happens if we suppose that f is not null-homotopic in my initial question

Comment: What about maps from $S^1\times S^1\to S^2$. There are degree 1 maps that are thus not nullhomotopic which have fold singularities. For example attach a tiny two handle to a sphere and look at the map that pushes it back down.

Comment: @HenrikRüping: is this comment for me or GSM?  Your comment is completely consistent with the Whitney perspective.  For maps $S^1 \times S^1 \to S^2$, if you could get rid of the fold singularities it would be a covering map.  But there's no way to remove the fold singularities.

Comment: No it was refering to @GSM s comment whether adding the not null-homotopic-assumption removes the counterexamples.